# PHP Routing with multilingual support

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-routing, multilingual, seo

I am currently creating a CMS on a framework. I have made my .htaccess file, which looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

My problem is, that:

1) My pages can be accessed with the normal MVC URL:
http://example.com/pages/view/{the-shorttag-of-the-page}

2) My pages is also accessible with a route:
http://example.com/p/{the-shorttag-of-the-page}

What I really need to implement is that I can access it in two ways:
http://example.com/{the-shorttag-of-the-page}
Or with language support
http://example.com/{lang}/{the-shorttag-of-the-page}

My problem is that I don't want to change the mod_rewrite - I rather want to make the routes in PHP, but I can't find a solution of how to route to the PageController->view() method without having a static letter ("p" in the upper example) in the conditions.

Do you understand my question?
And do you have some tips, that could lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you need to implement some kind of router.

I've faced it myself and this is how I made it work quite good:

Some router class parses the URL. It explodes URL parts (`/en/controller/action/param1/paramval1/`) into pieces. It determines language code (default if not provided), controller, action, etc.
Router also provides information (controller, action names, parameters) to other parts of the system, although you may implement special class for that purpose (eg. Request).

Now different parts of the system have access to given information via Router or Request class. From here on, it should be easy to implement multilangual site.

Once again, the important part is mapping URL to controller and action. Definitely, if you don't want URL like `/controller/action/parameter1`, you should have some mapping table (XML document / database table) that maps a stub (page short tag) to controller and action. It is the router that reads this table and determines controller, action and other parameters based on the given rules.

Hope I didn't complicate too much :)

**Update:**

As for myself, I've implemented mapping with XML file. Let me explain further: router takes care of resolving the URL. Normally, your URL would contain the controller and action name (in your case, *pages* is the controller, *view* is the action).

Now in your case, you want just a stub, so router must somehow obtain the information about which controller and action is being called. That is the purpose of mapping, to map the stub to appropriate controller and action.

I've implemeted this as static routes, written manually into XML file, but you could for example use some kind of plugin class that checks if stub actually relates to a page. If it doesn't, that can mean two things: it is a controller or request is invalid.

Let me talk further about collisions: if stub is the same as the name of any controller, you have a collision. Should you render a page with a given stub, or call the controller? That has to resolved somehow, perhaps you can programatically restrict user to have a page with that kind of stubs.

Also, next time you dive into application development with PHP, I'd recommend you using some well-known PHP framework (if you don't already, ofc.), e.g. Zend, Kohana or CodeIgniter. They all provide router and many other components that make developing applications much easier, faster and more secure.

Comment: A little complicated about the last part - why should I have a mapping database? And what is the purpose of this? It is the first time I have faced the language-support problems, so it is not what i am best at..

Comment: updated the answer with more detailed explanation about mapping

Comment: Usoban: I am a little more into your thinking now. But I need to ask a little question: Does this mean, that I have to get all the shorttags from my database and check if any of these is in the URL. If not, then I should create a dispatcher, that routes to a controller, if this exists. If none of these exists, then route to an error page.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, each page in database should have stub (you're calling it short-tag :), which is stripped out page title (eg. about-page, our-company). It's just a matter of SQL query.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language. By 'stub' do you mean an 'alias'?

Comment: we're talking about this parameter http://example.com/{the-shorttag-of-the-page}. So stub == page short tag == alias, some value that uniquely identifies the page, most commonly you programatically generate it from the page title.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing that by passing the entire string after the domain to the index page, and processing it in php, not in .htaccess. I'm not an .htaccess expert, but this is working for me:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

I specify in the setup if the site will or will not use lang support, I think support both in the same site could be hard to implement.

Ask me please if you need more details.

**UPDATED**

Dennis, I was reading @usoban post and I could say I have a similar approach. As I said, I get the full path after the domain from .htaccess to my `application` class and parse it to an array. If 'multilanguage' is specified in config, I take the first array element and load the 'alias' table for that language.

The 'alias' table is an associative array that map alias-controller, like this:

```
$lang_mods = array(
    'home'      => 'Home',
    'contact'   => 'Contact',
    'sitemap'   => 'Sitemap',
    'about'     => 'Section/about',
    'terms'     => 'Section/terms',
);
```

In this way, I can have a fully translated url, i.e:

http://www.example.com/en/contact
and:
http://www.example.com/es/contacto

So, after removing the first language element from the url array, I check the next element against the alias table. Last two items in the table are special cases that can be used in order to simplify the url, getting

http://www.example.com/en/about
instead of
http://www.example.com/en/section/about
that looks better, but both pointing to the same `Section` controller.

After removing language and alias, the remaining elements in the array -if any- are passed to the controller. 'about' or 'terms' in the example, are prepended in the argument array. Depending on the controller, the first argument can be an action or not.

If in some step of this process, something doesn't match the allowed values, it's redirected to the home page.

Ok, in your case, maybe if the first argument (or the second if the site is multilanguage) could be checked against the available controllers, if it doesn't exist, you could route to a 'default' controller, and then checking against the available pages in your db. In this way you could avoid the need of having an additional `/p/` in the url.

I tried to be clear, sorry, English is not my native language ;)

Comment: This is what I do at the moment. My problem is, that I need the PHP-code for how to do it.

I have made a table with languages.. If there is more than one language, then there should be language support

Comment: I do it in my framework, but I can't give you a short answer because my language support is integrated with many other functionality. I will try to make a brief later. (Sorry about my english)

Comment: That sounds really great! It is my last head-acke in my CMS.. and I really don't want to make som "OOOPS" :P

Comment: I added more details, take a look.

Comment: Okay, now I am some way more near my ending point. :P Well, what you say is: explode URL by "/" and then take the first part. If it is not exactly 2 characters long, then it is not a language - so choose the default language.
If it IS 2 characters long, then dump EVERY page from the language to an array where you specify controller, action and e.g. some extra variables?

Comment: That's right. In my case, if 'multilanguage' is specified in config, the first element in the array MUST be the langauage and, the supplied language must exist in an array of allowed languages. Also in my case, I don't have different pages for different languages, I have a file per controller per language that include an associative array of localized strings. And a function that return the right string for the selected language. About having a default language if it's not provided, it could be, but it would require some extra parsing.

Comment: Well this is quite helpful!

I my case I have a "Pages"-controller, which shall handle everything. How do you handle your controllers? Because my problem is, that the user can add languages in the CMS, so there can't be a controller pr. language. :)

Comment: Not sure about the question and not sure if I my explanation was clear. I have only one controller for each 'section' of the site, and every controller may have a array of strings for every allowed language (there is a folder for each language and a file may exist there for each controller). That is for labels, short texts and messages. Long formatted texts are stored in the db and edited in a section of the backend.

Comment: In my case, user can't add new languages. If you allow it, maybe you could have a section in your backend where you list those strings and allow to edit the translation in a second column. I guess I have seen similar solutions elsewhere. In that case you probably must store them in the db, maybe you can save it in only one field in JSON format an load it enterely at the begining.